# How to get Samsung Android Device Name programmatically?

Tags: android

Other similar questions in SO are answered by retrieving the Build.MODEL name.

But what I would really like is to get the customizable Device name on Samsung Devices.  I know it is customizable because on my Galaxy Note, I can change it from the settings->About device.  For example, below, I would like to retrieve the "Milky Way" string.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no common way getting this, since it's not a "android-feature" more likely a Samsung Feature afaik.

Try getting it with this, which worked on my galaxy s3, s4 and s5

```
BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String deviceName = myDevice.getName();
```

Do not forget to add the bluetooth permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Emanuel S this code snippet helps a lot. But found a limitation with the code. When Bluetooth is OFF and changed the name of the phone, the code didn't provide newly changed phone name until Bluetooth is turned ON again. Please help in handling this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String deviceName = myDevice.getName();
```

still returns the SM-G900H.

After some research I found the device_name in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/da‌​tabases/settings‌​.db

I manage to get it using following shell command

```
settings get system device_name
```

Code:

```
String deviceName = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "device_name");
```

Comment: its return null on samsung device

Comment: look at the device_name in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/da‌​tabases/settings‌​.db

Comment: It worked for me for both yours and his solution above bro. maybe use missed runtime permission.

Answer (score 0):

Settings.Global.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "device_name")
It working for me.